# Redis: Storing a hash map in a set

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm using `Jedis` to store some documents on `Redis`.
I have the following class:

```
public class Document{
      public String id;
      public String title;
      public Map<String, Keyword> keywords = new HashMap<>();
  }
```

I used `sadd` to add a set to Redis. I tried the following code:

```
Document d = new Document();
jedis.sadd(d.id,d.title);
```

But I don't know how to add the map in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach, afaik, is to serialize the map before adding it to the set. Note that Redis' sets are made of unique members, where each member is a string value (byte stream in the Java world iirc).

Comment: what do you mean by serializing?

Comment: I mean converting to some representation that can be stored as a Redis string - it can be a text-only (e.g. JSON) value or any other encoding whether ready-made (e.g. MessagePack), handmade or if the language/framework offers this as a capability (idk about Java).

Comment: :) java.io.serializable as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067689/how-to-serialize-a-map-in-java-to-store-on-redis