# How to serialize a map in Java to store in Redis?

Tags: java, serialization, redis

I have the following classes:

```
public class Document {

    public String id;
    public String date;
    public Map<String, Keyword> keywords = new HashMap<>();

}

public class Keyword {

    public String word;
    public Map<String, Document> docs = new HashMap<>();

}
```

I want to serialize the `keywords` HashMap in order to save it in Redis.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string) but it throws an error:

> java.io.NotSerializableException:keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `Keyword` and `Document` classes implement `java.io.Serializable`.

Everything what you are trying to serialize should implement `java.io.Serializable`, `HashMap` and `String` by default are serializable so you need not to do anything for them.

Please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make Keyword implement `java.io.Serializable`